# Definite articles in multilingual Chicago-style bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex-chicago, german, chicago-style

[Preface: Not a super advanced LaTeX user.] I'm trying to create a Chicago-note style bibliography using `biblatex-chicago` in Overleaf and running into trouble with a particular case concerning the alphabetization of titles that span more than one language.

The Chicago convention is that, assuming we're looking at multiple works by a single author, a definite article like "the" is disregarded when determining how to alphabetize a title, meaning titles that begin with "the" would be categorized under the first letter of the following word — e.g., *The Lord of the Rings* would fall under "L" (from "*Lord*") rather than "T" (from "*The*"). However, in my particular case, I have two works by the same author: (1) *The Fundamental Concepts of Metaphysics* and (2) *Die Grundbegriffe der Metaphysik*. The former is the English translation of the German latter, so both titles begin with a definite article in their respective languages.

The issue here is that, according to convention, (2) should be alphabetized as a title beginning with "G," placing it below (1) which begins with "F." Yet when I generate my bibliography, (2) appears *above* (1), understood to be a title beginning with "D," as there doesn't seem to be a way for `biblatex-chicago` to recognize disregardable definite articles when they're not in English. Is there something I can do to correct the sequencing of these titles in my bibliography?

.bib file:

```
% Saved as "bib.bib"

@book{FCM,
author = {Martin Heidegger},
title = {The Fundamental Concepts of Metaphysics: World, Finitude, Solitude},
shorttitle = {Fundamental Concepts of Metaphysics},
translator = {William McNeill and Nicholas Walker},
publisher = {Indiana University Press},
location = {Bloomington},
year = {1995}
}
@book{GdM,
author = {Martin Heidegger},
title = {Die Grundbegriffe der Metaphysik. Welt – Endlichkeit – Einsamkeit \textnormal{(Freiburger Vorlesung Wintersemester 1929/30)}},
sorttitle = {Grundbegriffe der Metaphysik},
shorttitle = {Grundbegriffe der Metaphysik},
editor = {Friedrich-Wilhelm von Herrmann},
publisher = {Vittorio Kostermann},
location = {Frankfurt am Main},
year = {1983}
}
```

.tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You only have a `shorttitle` in `FCM` and no `sorttitle`. That means that this entry is still sorted by `title`: `The Fundamental Concepts of Metaphysics: World, Finitude, Solitude`. Unless you also have the code to strip the "The" from my answer (which the MWE does not) this will be sorted under "T".

Comment: I guess that makes sense, but it was my understanding that `biblatex-chicago` would automatically ignore (English) definite articles, as that is the style convention, and that I'd only need to create a `sorttitle` for `GdM`. Is that not the case? In other words, shouldn't "The Fundamental Concepts …" by default be sorted as "Fundamental Concepts …"?

Comment: I couldn't find any code in `biblatex-chicago` to the effect that it would automatically strip (English) articles. Indeed the documentation says "Still, some entries without a name field of any sort, particularly those with a definite or indefinite article beginning the title , may require assistance (`greek:filmstrip`, `grove:sibelius`, `nyt:obittrevor`, `virginia:plantation`)." suggesting to me that articles are not generally stripped. My answer shows a way to get rid of "The" at the beginning of `titles` for sorting purposes automatically, or you use `sorttitle` as recommended.

Comment: If you think `biblatex-chicago` should attempt to strip (English) articles before sorting, you can always contact the `biblatex-chicago` developer. (Contact details can be found in the documentation.) From what I can tell, he is very happy to take suggestions to improve his package.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see `biblatex-chicago` does not attempt to strip articles (English or German) before sorting.

---

You can use the `sorttitle` field to give a "sortable" version of the title. For example

```
sorttitle = {Grundbegriffe der Metaphysik},
```

---

For a more automatic solution you can try `\DeclareNosort` and give a list of articles that need to be dropped for sorting purposes. (Of course "Die" is tricky, because it could be both English and German.) For example

```
\DeclareNosort{
  \nosort{settitles}{\regexp{\AThe\s+}}
}
```

Comment: @petzorna Post a fully compilable example document.

Comment: Sorry for the delay — was trying to figure out how to embed a .bib file within a .tex file but to no avail. I've added the code for separate .bib and .tex files to my question above; hope that's okay!